# Query Transform and Pivot

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a very subtle problem and I'm unable to solve it until now.
Let's take an example to better explain the problem:

I have a table *Person*:
With fields: ID, Name, Option1, Option1_Value, Option2, Option2_Value, Option3, Option3_Value

I want a query that shows the following:

```
ID      Name      Reason
1       Clark     Option1 doesn't match, Option2 doesn't match
2       Stefan    Option3 doesn't match
3       Sandra    (No errors: well just ignore this line)
4       Steven    Option2 doesn't match
```

So what has to be done is: for every option field, do a check (a query that's going to read and compare the option_value using an external table) and then print the options that doesn't match but in ONE field that serves as an error output field.

Is it possible to achieve this using Transform and Pivot ?
If so, could you please provide me with tips and advise on how should I use them ?
If not, is there an alternative ? Or maybe something I can do VBA-side ?

Thank you in advance guys
Miloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table already has the three options in a row, so how about:

```
SELECT ID, Name, 
     IIf(Option1_Value<>"Something","Option1 dosn't match",
        IIf (Option2_Value<>"Something","Option2 dosn't match",
           IIf( Option3_Value<>"Something","Option3 dosn't match","No errors")))
     As Reason
FROM Table
```

It is not quite clear from your post what the options do not match, nor is it clear what is the difference between Option and Option_Value.

Comment: Dude ! You rock ma world ! I totally forgot about the IIF clause ! Thank you very much I'm going to give it a shot and get back to you and validate the answer if it solves my problem (well it should :P) ! Really BIG THANKS !

Comment: As written, I don't think this will produce the output shown in the question. It looks like if Option 1 doesn't match it won't even check the other options. "Clark" is shown with two errors. Of course, the root of the problem is the attribute/value table structure (sometimes appropriate, but best avoided in most cases).

Comment: RolandTumble thank you for your feedback, but actually I adapted Remou's conditions to my need and it works perfectly I separated every option check in a single IIF and concatenated all the IIFs' outputs something like:    IIF (opt1 test,"...","...") + IIF (opt2 test,"...","...") + ... etc. Thx again